# Google v3 Calendar API now reports IPv6 connection error but worked yesterday

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am getting an error when calling the Google Calendar v3 API via PHP to pull in events which were displayed in a list.

Yesterday (and for several months prior) this worked without a problem. Today neither return events. Turning on debug gives me this error (domain name obfuscated with XXXX):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_IOException' with message 'HTTP Error: (0) Failed to connect to 2a00:1450:4009:80a::200d: Network is unreachable' in /home/sites/XXXX.org.uk/public_html/events/google-api/io/Google_CurlIO.php:123
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sites/XXXX.org.uk/public_html/events/google-api/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(270): Google_CurlIO->makeRequest(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#1 /home/sites/XXXX.org.uk/public_html/events/google-api/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(265): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)
#2 /home/sites/XXXX.org.uk/public_html/events/google-api/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(218): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenWithAssertion()
#3 /home/sites/XXXX.org.uk/public_html/events/google-api/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(167): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#4 /home/sites/XXXX.org.uk/public_html/events/google-api/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php(529): Google_ServiceResource->__call('list', Array)
#5 /home/sites/XXXX.org.uk/pub in /home/sites/XXXX.org.uk/public_html/events/google-api/io/Google_CurlIO.php on line 123
```

Please can anyone suggest what may have caused this?

Searching Google for the Failed to connect error suggests either that the host cannot connect to Google (but they're not reporting any outages) or that an IPv6 address of the host needs adding to the Google Developer Console (but I cannot find the "Connections" option for this and it appears to have been removed in the old and new console).

As mentioned, this worked yesterday and has been live with no issue for several months.
Thanks.

Comment: can you ping the ip from your server?

Comment: Ok, solved it. This occurs when the host blocks access to Google. The host fixed that this morning and all is well.

Comment: Thanks Dagon, I tried using curl to hit Google from the server with no luck last night. This morning the host fixed whatever they broke.

Comment: glad it fixed itself. :-)